# How to pass an augment in super() correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

My class takes an augment called resource:

```
> AClass(resource="123")
```

Class:

```
 class AClass(Base):
        def __init__(self, resource):
            super(AClass, self).__init__(self)
```

Which will be set in the Base class it extends from.

```
class BaseHTTP(object):
    def __init__(self, resource, data=None):
        self.resource = resource
```

In Python 2.7 what should I be doing to make sure the base class gets these arguments, is this OK...

```
super(Get, self).__init__(self, resource)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not pass `self` to `super(...).__init__`, as `super(...).__init__` returns the bound method:

```
 class AClass(Base):
        def __init__(self, resource):
            super(AClass, self).__init__(resource)
```

Also, I'm not sure what `Get` is. Usually `super`'s first argument should be the class from which it is called -- in this case, `AClass`.

---

Bonus trivia: `super(...).__new__`, in contrast, returns the *staticmethod*, since `__new__` is a staticmethod. So for `__new__`, `self` must still be passed:

```
super(...).__new__(self, ...)
```

Comment: N.B. the easiest way to ensure you use `super` correctly is to upgrade to Python3 :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @unutbu's excellent answer, let me point out the canonical use of this idiom.

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, species, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.species = species
        self.gender = gender
        self.children = []
    def make_kid(self, partner, child_name):
        if self.gender == "F":
            return Child(mom=self, dad=partner, name=child_name,
                         species=self.species, gender=random.choice(["M", "F"]))
        else:
            return Child(mom=partner, dad=self, name=child_name,
                         species=self.species, gender=random.choice(["M", "F"]))

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, mom=None, dad=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # a list of arguments we care about as a Child, followed by
        # *args, **kwargs that other classes further up the MRO may need
        self.mom = mom
        self.dad = dad
        # strip out the arguments we deal with here as a Child
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # then send the rest of them to the parent object

man = Parent("Adam","Human","M")
woman = Parent("Eve","Human","F")
child = man.make_kid(woman, "Junior")
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
class AClass(Base):
    def __init__(self, resource):
        Base.__init__(self, resource)
```

But @unutbu solution is better, I think.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't do that. You're shooting your future self in the foot if you ever decide inherit from AClass.